# 'kill <thread id>' gives ERROR 1095 (HY000): You are not owner of thread ... even though I am

Tags: mariadb, galera

I did an `ALTER TABLE` on a huge table on a MariaDB Galera Cluster 10.2, but after a while of waiting I changed my mind and tried to kill the connection. However, MariaDB said `ERROR 1095 (HY000): You are not owner of thread 123` even though I most definitely am the owner. So what is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is misleading. Galera can mark user threads as high priority which means they can't be killed. Currently, this gives the `ERROR 1095 (HY000): You are not owner of thread`... See [MDEV-12008](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12008) for details.

This will probably affect other distributions of Galera as well, such as Percona XtraDB Cluster.

Comment: How did you end killing the query?

Comment: @nbari I couldn't, I waited until it finished.