# Cannot write to Galera Cluster (Lock wait timeout)

Tags: mariadb, galera

My Galera cluster has gone down / locked up, I can read from all databases, but I cannot write to any table in any database, it just locks / waits forever.

I can fix it by shutting down all 3 mariadb servers and start a new cluster, but I want to know what's going on for obvious reasons. Is there any way to figure out what's happening? It happened 5 days ago, and now again.

Edit:
Extra info, it gave me this error after I set a connect timeout: 
`ERROR 1205 (HY000) at line 1: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

Edit 2: `show processlist` gave me this at the top:

```
|       1 | system user      |            | NULL              | Sleep   | 434414 | WSREP aborter idle       | NULL                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
|       2 | system user      |            | NULL              | Sleep   |  44098 | Waiting for table flush  | INSERT INTO `cron_log` SET
                                `start` = '1566429001',
                                `end` = '1566429004',
```

is there something I can do from a user perspective or is this an internal mariadb error?

I cannot seem to kill process 2, logged in as root is says: `You are not owner of thread 2`

Edit 3:

> Are you writing to all 3 nodes, or do you have a dedicated write node?

I WAS writing to all three nodes but kind of got the feeling it's better to write to just one, which is also the goal of MaxScale by MariaDB. However, the goal of a galera cluster is that you can write to all, but apparently in practice it's not a great idea, which is kinda awkward if you ask me but OK.
Also, I had a OPTIMIZE statement in my application and got to understand that could cause "Waiting for FLUSH" issues, so I worked around that statement so it's no longer needed.

> "shutting down all 3 mariadb servers and start a new cluster" -- Surely there is a less drastic solution! – Rick James

Well I tried quite some things, but shutting everything down and bootstrapping it again was the only thing that worked.

Comment: Are you writing to all 3 nodes, or do you have a dedicated write node?

Comment: "shutting down all 3 mariadb servers and start a new cluster" -- Surely there is a less drastic solution!

Comment: Step 1 is to identify what transaction is causing the problem.  With those details we can probably suggest a better index or some other way to speed it up, thereby eliminating the problem.  Look at the various logs.  Turn on the slowlog.  Turn on the general log.  Do `SHOW FULL PROESSLIST` _before_ it dies.  Etc.

Comment: Re: 'You are not owner of thread 2', see my answer here: ['kill <query id>' gives ERROR 1095 (HY000): You are not owner of thread … even though I am](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221591/kill-query-id-gives-error-1095-hy000-you-are-not-owner-of-thread-even).

Comment: I had the same issue. Turned out to be a `select *`hanging in `sending data` for a very long time (66269s). I killed that transaction, and all was well. Writes resumed functioning in all databases after that.